# Unable to enroll user in new org added to balance transfer sample

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following Balance transfer from Hyperledger Fabric samples from this [link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/balance-transfer#sample-rest-apis-requests). I have modified it a bit, now I have 3 Orgs with 1 Peer each. All goes fine till I enroll users to Org1 and Org2 but, when I try to enroll a user to my 3rd Org I get following error

> Failed to get registered user: xyz with error: Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":63,"message":"Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set"}]]

My Binaries of Hyperledger Fabric are from version 1.1.0 Alfa

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that the fabric-ca being used in the sample does not know about the affiliation.  By default, fabric-ca only has the following affiliations:

org1.department1
org1.department2
org2.department1

The [code](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/balance-transfer/app/helper.js#L91) which registers and enrolls users in the sample takes the org name and concatenates it with "department1" :

```
let secret = await caClient.register({
                enrollmentID: username,
                affiliation: userOrg.toLowerCase() + '.department1'
            }, adminUserObj);
```

So when you pass in Org3, it tries to register the user with the affiliation org3.department1 which does not exist.

Since you are using 1.1.0-alpha, you are in luck as this version of fabric-ca supports has an API for adding new affiliations.  The easiest way is to use the fabric-ca-client to do this:

```
fabric-ca-client affiliation add org3
fabric-ca-client affiliation add org3.department1
```

You can look at the fabric-ca docs ( http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/ ) for more details.  You'll need to first enroll the admin user which has the password "adminpw" with the fabric-ca-client and then run the above commands.

Comment: where shall i execute above commands? Do i have to setup fabric-ca locally? I tried to run one of the command but seems affiliation command is not available in my fabric-ca-client.

Comment: Thanks. It helped. was passing affiliation as Org1 overwriting default org1.department1. would love to understand how to manage our own affiliation if you can help.

Answer (score 12):

This may be useless (and very late), but I'd like to add to Gari's answer. You can also add affiliations using the node client SDK's [AffiliationService class](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/AffiliationService.html).
To do this in the balance transfer code, modify `helper.js` with:

```
let adminUserObj = await client.setUserContext({
                        username: admins[0].username, 
                        password: admins[0].secret});

let caClient = client.getCertificateAuthority();
let affiliationService = caClient.newAffiliationService();

let registeredAffiliations = await affiliationService.getAll(adminUserObj);
if(!registeredAffiliations.result.affiliations.some(
    x => x.name == userOrg.toLowerCase())){
        let affiliation = 'org3.department1'; 
        await affiliationService.create({
                        name: affiliation, 
                        force: true}, adminUserObj);
}
```

Note:
The above code only adds the affiliations (which I think is the only thing missing in your case). To successfully enroll a user for Org3, you'll also have specify  org3 in `artifacts/channel/cryptogen.yaml`, `artifacts/channel/configtx.yaml`, `artifacts/docker-compose.yaml`, `artifacts/network-config.yaml` and `config.json`. And create an `org3.yaml` file.

I built a [chaincode sample app](https://github.com/demonquark/hyperledger-escrow) with the balance transfer sample as a base which has 3 orgs. You can take a look at it to see the necessary changes.

Comment: where do you add this code in the helper.js ? can you post a full example with the initialisation of `client` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add more organizations and there departments by changing the fabric-ca-server-config by going to the fabric-ca docker container.

```
docker exec -it ca.org1.example.com bash
```

Go the `root@c3804e2852fd:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server#` directory inside the container

Now edit fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file. Add organizations and their departments as per your choice.

Below i have added one "Manufacturer" organization. You can add Org3 like this.

[image]

Comment: it worked for me, make sure to add it in the corresponding organisation  ca-org(num).example.com container i added to all the 3. now everything okay

Answer (score 1):

Please pay attention to this line in helper.js,

let secret = await caClient.register({
                enrollmentID: username,
                affiliation: **userOrg.toLowerCase()** + '.department1'
            }, adminUserObj);

Are you sure you are lowercasing for Org3 (in config yaml files) ?

Answer (score 1):

I had seen the same problem in fabric 1.3, I have changed the names and configured my own.
by removing below statement helped me

just comment the below line in 'helper.js' helped me.

`//affiliation: userOrg.toLowerCase() + '.department1'`

Answer (score 1):

Replace below function in app/helper.js file. Restart node server and try enrolling users on org3.

```
var getRegisteredUser = async function(username, userOrg, isJson) {
    try {
        var client = await getClientForOrg(userOrg);
        logger.debug('Successfully initialized the credential stores');
        // client can now act as an agent for organization Org1
        // first check to see if the user is already enrolled
        var user = await client.getUserContext(username, true);
        if (user && user.isEnrolled()) {
            logger.info('Successfully loaded member from persistence');
            var response = {
                success: false,
            };
            return response;
        } else {
        // user was not enrolled, so we will need an admin user object to register
            logger.info('User %s was not enrolled, so we will need an admin user object to register',username);
            var admins = hfc.getConfigSetting('admins');
            let adminUserObj = await client.setUserContext({username: admins[0].username, password: admins[0].secret});
            //newly added
            if(adminUserObj.getAffiliation() != userOrg.toLowerCase()){
                logger.info('Admin affiliation not registered. Registering now.');
                adminUserObj.setAffiliation(userOrg.toLowerCase());
                adminUserObj.setRoles(['peer','orderer','client','user']);
                adminUserObj = await client.setUserContext(adminUserObj);
            }
            logger.info('Admin User: %s', adminUserObj);
            let affiliation = userOrg.toLowerCase() + '.department1';
            let caClient = client.getCertificateAuthority();
            //check if org exists
            const affiliationService = caClient.newAffiliationService();
            const registeredAffiliations = await affiliationService.getAll(adminUserObj);
            if(!registeredAffiliations.result.affiliations.some(x => x.name == userOrg.toLowerCase())){
                logger.info('Register the new affiliation: %s ', affiliation);
                await affiliationService.create({name: affiliation, force: true}, adminUserObj);
            }
            let secret = await caClient.register({
                enrollmentID: username,
                affiliation: affiliation
            }, adminUserObj);
            logger.debug('Successfully got the secret for user %s — %s',username);

            user = await client.setUserContext({username:username, password:secret});
            logger.debug('Successfully enrolled username %s and setUserContext on the client object', username);

        }
        if(user && user.isEnrolled) {
            if (isJson && isJson === true) {
                var response = {
                    success: true,
                    secret: user._enrollmentSecret,
                    message: username + ' enrolled Successfully',
                };
                return response;
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error('User was not enrolled ');
        }
    } catch(error) {
            let message = 'Failed to register the username ' + username + ' for organization ' + userOrg + ' with error: ' + error.toString();
            logger.error(message);
            var response = {
            success: false,
            message: message,
        };
        return response;
    }
};
```

Comment: worked for me. I deleted all the previous docker container and crypto store files and then start the server and enrolled the user.