# Hyperledger Cello : Not able to issue new ID for Participant

Tags: hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-cello

I have deployed the hyper ledger network with default cello configuration on aws. The fabric is getting installed and it is up and run. By default, carauction-network is installed on both the organization which named as orga and orgb. Then with the help of the composer-playground, I have created a participant(Autioner) and tried to register an ID for it and getting below error.

`Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":63,"message":"Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set"}]]`

after searching and debugging found that composer is looking for org1 as an organization name. So modified the cello scripts and changed orga,orgb.. to org1,org2.. and it resolved the problem. Now I am able to create the participants for org1 but when I try to create participant for org2 still getting the same issue.

I am really not able to understand why the organization has this naming constraint. Is this a bug or we have to follow some naming convention ?? and if it is a naming constraint why I am not able to register an ID for org2??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that this is in regard to the affiliation names used by fabric-ca-servers. Composer playground, when it issues identities, is not setting any affiliation name and because of this will always default to 'org1'. It's not possible to set the affiliation in playground (as playground is not an operations tool, it is a tool to help developers) so you won't be able to use playground to perform identity management on a ca server that doesn't have an org1 affiliation defined.

The composer cli command `composer identity issue` does allow you to define the affiliation using the `-o` option, eg `-o affiliation=xyz`

`composer identity issue -c someadmin@somenetwork -u newUser -a org.mynetwork.Traders#TraderForCompanyA -o affiliation=CompanyA`

Comment: Thanks a lot, david. It helped me create the identity with above composer-cli commands. I would be grateful if you can direct me to some links where I can read more internals about it.

Comment: Affiliation is a Hyperledger Fabric specific concept - you can read more on it [here](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html?highlight=affiliation) in the Fabric CA User guide and in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836728/unable-to-enroll-user-in-new-org-added-to-balance-transfer-sample)