# Hyperledger Fabric: Registration of 'orderer1-ord' failed in affiliation validation: Failed getting affiliation 'ord.OU': :

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

we have customized the [fabric-ca](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/fabric-ca) sample to remove below line in [env.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/fabric-ca/scripts/env.sh)

```
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_ID_AFFILIATION=org1
```

and add `--id.affiliation $ORG.OU` in all calls to `fabric-ca-client register` or `enroll`. Example:

```
scripts/env.sh:   fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -u $ENROLLMENT_URL -M /tmp/tls --csr.hosts $HOST_NAME --csr.names O=$ORG --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/env.sh:      fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://$ADMIN_NAME:$ADMIN_PASS@$CA_HOST:7054 --csr.names O=$ORG --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/env.sh:      fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://$USER_NAME:$USER_PASS@$CA_HOST:7054 --csr.names O=$ORG --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/setup-fabric.sh:         fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name $ORDERER_NAME --id.secret $ORDERER_PASS --id.type orderer --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/setup-fabric.sh:      fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name $ADMIN_NAME --id.secret $ADMIN_PASS --id.attrs "admin=true:ecert" --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/setup-fabric.sh:         fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name $PEER_NAME --id.secret $PEER_PASS --id.type peer --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/setup-fabric.sh:      fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name $ADMIN_NAME --id.secret $ADMIN_PASS --id.attrs "hf.Registrar.Roles=client,hf.Registrar.Attributes=*,hf.Revoker=true,hf.GenCRL=true,admin=true:ecert" --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/setup-fabric.sh:      fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name $USER_NAME --id.secret $USER_PASS --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/setup-fabric.sh:      fabric-ca-client getcacert -d -u https://$CA_HOST:7054 -M $ORG_MSP_DIR --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/start-orderer.sh:fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -u $ENROLLMENT_URL -M /tmp/tls --csr.hosts $ORDERER_HOST --csr.names O=$ORG --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/start-orderer.sh:fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u $ENROLLMENT_URL -M $ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR --csr.names O=$ORG --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/start-peer.sh:fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -u $ENROLLMENT_URL -M /tmp/tls --csr.hosts $PEER_HOST --csr.names O=$ORG --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
scripts/start-peer.sh:fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u $ENROLLMENT_URL -M $CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH --csr.names O=$ORG --id.affiliation $ORG.OU
```

when we do this we see this error in setup.log:

```
Error: Response from server: Error Code: 0 - Registration of 'orderer1-ord' failed in affiliation validation: Failed getting affiliation 'ord.OU': : scode: 404, code: 63, msg: Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set
```

If we modify [enrollCAADmin](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/fabric-ca/scripts/setup-fabric.sh) to add:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/48840929/147530
   fabric-ca-client affiliation add $1
```

we now see this error:

```
Error: Response from server: Error Code: 60 - Affiliation already exists
```

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding affiliation of `$ORG.OU` fails but adding affiliation of `$ORG` works. In setup-fabric.sh, function registerPeerIdentities

```
fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name $ADMIN_NAME --id.secret $ADMIN_PASS --id.attrs "hf.Registrar.Roles=client,hf.Registrar.Attributes=*,hf.Revoker=true,hf.GenCRL=true,admin=true:ecert,abac.init=true:ecert" --id.affiliation=$ORG
      log "Registering user identity with $CA_NAME"
      fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name $USER_NAME --id.secret $USER_PASS --id.affiliation=$ORG
```

note following section in `$FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` of `rca-myorg1`

```
root@cad23a1fb013:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca# cat fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
affiliations:
   ord: []
   myorg1: []
   myorg2: []
   myorg3: []
   org1:
      - department1
      - department2
   org2:
      - department1
```

from https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#registering-a-new-identity

> The affiliation of the registrar must be equal to or a prefix of the
>   affiliation of the identity being registered. For example, an
>   registrar with an affiliation of “a.b” may register an identity with
>   an affiliation of “a.b.c” but may not register an identity with an
>   affiliation of “a.c”. If root affiliation is required for an identity,
>   then the affiliation request should be a dot (”.”) and the registrar
>   must also have root affiliation. If no affiliation is specified in the
>   registration request, the identity being registered will be given the
>   affiliation of the registrar.

so not sure why setting affiliation to `$ORG` works but `$ORG.OU` does not