# Failed getting affiliation 'org3.department1 : : scode: 404, code: 63, msg: Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

**I followed below steps of Hyperledger Fabric Balance Transfer Application (1.4.3 version):**

1. I have made a copy of balance transfer application and created a new project.
2. Did required changes in below files

   artifacts/channel/crytogen.yaml
      artifacts/channel/configtx.yaml
      artifacts/channel/docker-compose.yaml
      artifacts/network-config.yaml
      artifacts/org3.yaml
      config.js
      app/instantiate-chaincode.js
3. Started the network, everything went fine.

If I register user with orgName Org1 or Org2 everything works fine.

But when I tried to register user on Org3 from this api,
   **curl -s -X POST http://localhost:4000/users -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=Ramesh&orgName=Org3'**

It is showing this error : **Failed getting affiliation 'org3.department1 : : scode: 404, code: 63, msg: Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set**

By default, fabric-ca only has the following affiliations:

org1.department1 
org1.department2

org2.department1

So I tried to add below commands in bash terminal, **docker exec -it  bash **.

**fabric-ca-client affiliation add org3 

fabric-ca-client affiliation add org3.department1**

Still getting same error.

Also I tried to add new org details in fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file and gave that path in docker-compose.yaml file volumes for all 3 orgs ca containers .

**volumes:

      - ./channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config 

      - ../ca-server-config/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml**

Restarted the netowrk, but it is showing below error,

**ERROR: for ca.org3.example.com  Cannot start service ca.org3.example.com: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\"/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/newProject/ca-server-config/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml\\" to rootfs \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/03d0b6d5e25572670c817f37b1a791938de81835680cce9f11f5d2c0f05d6320/merged\\" at \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/03d0b6d5e25572670c817f37b1a791938de81835680cce9f11f5d2c0f05d6320/merged/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type**

Please suggest on above error and how can i add new org in balance transfer application?

Comment: Similar question already answered [Unable to enroll user in new org added to balance transfer sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836728/unable-to-enroll-user-in-new-org-added-to-balance-transfer-sample)

Comment: Similar question already answered [**Unable to enroll user in new org added to balance transfer sample**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836728/unable-to-enroll-user-in-new-org-added-to-balance-transfer-sample)